# Inconsistent temperature recommendations on different roasting thermometers

Tags: equipment, temperature, thermometer

I'm looking at two different roasting thermometers of the same brand and I'm wondering why they have different temperature recommendations for the same kinds of meat.

[image: TFA 14.1002] [image: TFA 14.1028]

For example, the first one (TFA 14.1002) recommends a temperature of 85°C for pork, but the second one (TFA 14.1028) recommends only 73°C.

Why is there a difference? Are the lower recommendations on the second one unsafe?

Comment: The required temperature for pork was lowered a few years ago.  And the chicken one is problematic because there are different temperatures for breast vs thigh meat.  Also, could these be for sale in different countries that have different regulations?

Comment: Have you contacted the manufacturer? They may be able to provide you with the most accurate answer.

Answer (score 3):

"Safe" is not a property of the natural world waiting to be discovered. It's a matter of standardization. A regulatory body determines criteria to be applied such that a food item can be pronounced safe.

We can't know why the two thermometers' designers have decided to show different temperatures. Maybe they used two different safety standards, either created by two different regulatory agencies, or two different versions of the same standard (standards get changed with time). Note that TFA Dostmann is a German company and as far as I know, the BfR (which should be the relevant agency in Germany) has not published a temperature table for meat preparation. So it's possible that the thermometer designers didn't refer to an official standard, but tried to make rhyme of whatever safety information they were able to come across.

Another explanation is that the thermometers' display may be geared not towards safety, but towards quality. People have different preferences when it comes to what is the best taste, so for some, meat roasted to 73 internal is better than when roasted to 75, and for others it's the other way around.